# How to connect to Office365 SMTP with STARTTLS? I keep getting "send hello first" error

Tags: android, smtp, office365, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to connect to Office365 SMTP server with STARTTLS (on smtp.office365.com port 587). When I send `AUTH PLAIN` it says `503 5.5.2 Send hello first`. What am I doing wrong?

This is my conversation with server:

`02-03 02:58:56.951: I/System.out(1547): 220 MEXPR01CA0064.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 3 Feb 2016 07:58:55 +0000
02-03 02:58:59.781: I/System.out(1547): EHLO codolutions.com
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-MEXPR01CA0064.outlook.office365.com Hello [49.180.156.25]
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-SIZE 157286400
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-PIPELINING
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-DSN
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
02-03 02:59:12.841: I/System.out(1547): 250-STARTTLS
02-03 02:59:12.851: I/System.out(1547): 250-8BITMIME
02-03 02:59:12.851: I/System.out(1547): 250-BINARYMIME
02-03 02:59:12.851: I/System.out(1547): 250 CHUNKING
02-03 02:59:14.591: I/System.out(1547): STARTTLS
02-03 02:59:14.661: I/System.out(1547): 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
02-03 02:59:21.421: I/System.out(1547): AUTH PLAIN
02-03 02:59:26.491: I/System.out(1547): 503 5.5.2 Send hello first`

I have also tried sending STARTTLS before EHLO, also tried sending HELO instead, no luck.

P.S. I'm using Apache Commons Net in Android.

Comment: On which command it says "Send hello first"?

Comment: Please see the last line of the conversation above.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
I had to send another HELO/EHLO after STARTTLS (#WTF).